# No aparece mi dispositivo USB en WSL 2

Tags: wsl, usb, kali-linux, windows11

### El problema se resume en lo siguiente:

Tengo un ***SD Card*** que quiero montar en ***WSL 2 - Kali Linux*** desde ***Windows 11***. Pero al mostrar los dispositivos USB con `lsblk`, no obtengo ningún resultado diferente (estando conectada o desconectada mi SD, el resultado que arroja `lsblk` es el mismo). Por lo que no sé cuál imagen o disco debería montar.

Para ello (*basándome en [ésta guía](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/connect-usb)*) instalé ***usbipd*** en ***Windows 11***. Primero pido una lista de los dispositivos que tengo:

```
C:\Users\ok>usbipd list
Connected:
BUSID  VID:PID    DEVICE                                                        STATE
1-4    13d3:56c6  HD Camera                                                     Not shared
1-10   8087:0aaa  Intel(R) Wireless Bluetooth(R)                                Not shared
2-2    aaaa:8816  Dispositivo de almacenamiento USB                             Shared
2-3    0000:3825  Dispositivo de entrada USB                                    Not shared

Persisted:
GUID                                  DEVICE
58b7a15d-5204-48ab-a7f5-cc8d4bad498a  Bulk-In, Interface

usbipd: warning: USB filter 'USBPcap' is known to be incompatible with this software; 'bind --force' will be required.
```

Después ingreso el siguiente comando (desde ***WSL 2 - Kali Linux***) para conectar mi tarjeta SD

```
┌──(root㉿DESKTOP-IC4BUAE)-[~]
└─# usbip attach -r 172.22.144.1 -b 2-2
```

Ahora listo los dispositivos USB, y ahí está `"MXT micro SD CardReader"`:

```
┌──(root㉿DESKTOP-IC4BUAE)-[~]
└─# lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 016: ID aaaa:8816 MXT microSD CardReader
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Después listo los dispositivos de almacenamiento conectados y salen esos:

```
┌──(root㉿DESKTOP-IC4BUAE)-[~]
└─# lsblk
NAME  MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
loop0   7:0    0 333.4M  1 loop /mnt/wsl/docker-desktop/cli-tools
loop1   7:1    0 315.6M  1 loop
sda     8:0    0 389.8M  1 disk
sdb     8:16   0     1G  0 disk [SWAP]
sdc     8:32   0     1T  0 disk /mnt/wsl/docker-desktop/docker-desktop-proxy
sdd     8:48   0     1T  0 disk /mnt/wsl/docker-desktop-data/isocache
sde     8:64   0     1T  0 disk /mnt/wslg/distro
                                /
```

Como no supe identificar cuál disco era, traté desconectando el dispositivo desde PowerShell:

```
PS C:\Users\ok> usbipd detach -b 2-2
```

Y volviendo a listar los dispositivos dentro de WSL ahora ya no aparece mi SD:

```
    ┌──(root㉿DESKTOP-IC4BUAE)-[~]
    └─# lsusb
    Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
    Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Pero con `lsblk`, da exactamente el mismo resultado que cuando la SD estaba conectada:

```
┌──(root㉿DESKTOP-IC4BUAE)-[~]
└─# lsblk
NAME  MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
loop0   7:0    0 333.4M  1 loop /mnt/wsl/docker-desktop/cli-tools
loop1   7:1    0 315.6M  1 loop
sda     8:0    0 389.8M  1 disk
sdb     8:16   0     1G  0 disk [SWAP]
sdc     8:32   0     1T  0 disk /mnt/wsl/docker-desktop/docker-desktop-proxy
sdd     8:48   0     1T  0 disk /mnt/wsl/docker-desktop-data/isocache
sde     8:64   0     1T  0 disk /mnt/wslg/distro
                                /
```

Es decir, a partir de haber usado el comando `attach` de ***usbip***, ya no sé si sea necesario hacer otro paso más para que tu dispositivo aparezca al hacer `lsblk`. Y ya he visto varios tutoriales, pero terminan en que uno hace `lsusb` y ya, o en que uno hace `lsblk` y ahí te aparece un dispositivo nuevo y ése es el que montas. Pero a mí no me sale ningún dispositivo nuevo y no sé si sea normal en ***WSL 2*** o si alguno de los que ya me aparecen son los que debería montar (en lugar de esperar que aparezca uno nuevo).

De forma gráfica tampoco me aparece mi SD:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Desde DiskDrill en Windows, así luce mi SD, no sé si el hecho de estar particionada tenga algo que ver o no:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La verdad soy un novato un linux. Alguien por favor que supiera la solución a mi problema, se lo agradecería. Sólo quiero poder acceder a los archivos que tiene mi SD.

Comment: Creo que no es el sitio más adecuado para ese tipo de preguntas. Aquí hablamos sobre programación. Tal vez en [su] tengas mejor suerte. Por cierto, aquí hay un artículo en la documentación https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/connect-usb

Comment: Quizás esto te llame la atención: https://fredyfx.com/post/instalacion-parrot-sec-en-wsl2 está ligeramente relacionado. Saludos.